# unable to open the ticket in Red-Mine from From Gmail

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to open ticket in RedMine from Gmail. Getting below error -

below is the command i am trying to execute  -

`rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com port=143 username=my_gmail_id password=****** folder=inbox project=my_project_name allow_override=project,tracker,priority`

`WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.3
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
rake aborted!
LoadError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/ubuntu/redmine-3.4.6-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
/home/ubuntu/redmine-3.4.6-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in require'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-3.4.6-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-3.4.6-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/application.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/redmine-3.4.6-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile:5:in <top (required)>'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, you need to mention ruby located on the script.

/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.5/rake -f /var/www/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=your.host.com port=993 ssl=1 username=mail..com password=xxxx unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 project="general" tracker="your_tracker" allow_override=project,tracker,priority